# Font rendering issue Roboto "g" Internet Explorer / Firefox on Windows

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, fonts

I have an issue rendering the Roboto font on IE9 for the letter `g` only :

[image]

As you can see, the `g` letter is cropped to the right.

I tried changing the `letter-spacing`, the `font-size` and the `font-width` but nothing helped.

The font is `Roboto Italic`, in `Roboto normal`, the display is good :

[image]

Do you know what can be the explanation behind this?

**Note:**

- On Google Chrome (last version) on OSX and Firefox 31 on OSX   it
  renders good.
- On Firefox 42 on Windows it renders the same.

Comment: Is it working in other browsers ?

Comment: Yes, I'll edit my question.

Answer (score 0):

`letter-spacing` should work in your case.

As you can see in thisJSFiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/e0dgsd7u/), it is efficient.

And what an amazing news : IE9 should support it ! :) http://caniuse.com/#search=letter-spacing

### EDIT

If it is still not working, all I can advice you is to change the font only on IE.

E.g :

```
<!--[if IE]>
<style type="text/css">
  @font-face...
</style>
<![endif]-->
```

Hope you'll be able to avoid that.

Comment: As said in the question, I tried changing the letter spacing but the render was the same.

Comment: Yes but is it looking good other browsers with or without letter-spacing ?

Comment: It looks good in other browsers with and without `letter-spacing`.